# How to set the slider to move automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I want to move slider automatically in particular time in vertical position. Here is my code for slider

**Html code**

```
<script>
    $.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.slideshow';
</script>
<div class="slideshow vertical" data-cycle-fx=carousel data-cycle-timeout=0 data-cycle-next="#next3" data-cycle-prev="#prev3" data-cycle-carousel-visible=2 data-cycle-carousel-vertical=true>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg">
</div>
<div class="center">
    <button id="prev3">∧ Prev</button>
    <button id="next3">∨ Next</button>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.slideshow {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 312px!important;
}
.slideshow img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 2px;
}
div.responsive img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto
}
.cycle-pager {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 5px
}  
div.vertical {
    width: 100px
}
```

[jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uXPx/228/)

Or is there any news feed template which will move in vertical position?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your existing code, you can use `setInterval()` and trigger a click event on your "next" button.

```js
var paused = false,
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      (!paused) && $('#next3').trigger('click');
    },3000);
$('.slideshow, .controls').hover(function() {
  paused = true;
},function() {
  paused = false;
});
```

```css
.slideshow {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 312px!important;
}
.slideshow img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 2px;
}
div.responsive img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto
}
.cycle-pager {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 5px
}
div.vertical {
    width: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.slideshow';
</script>
<div class="slideshow vertical" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-next="#next3" data-cycle-prev="#prev3" data-cycle-carousel-visible="2" data-cycle-carousel-vertical="true">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg">
</div>
<div class="controls center">
    <button id="prev3">∧ Prev</button>
    <button id="next3">∨ Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: will it hold when user do the mouse hover?

Comment: Can you change your name into JqueryMaster?. How many years of experience?.